# Docker vs Mysql local server SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003]

Tags: php, mysql, docker, zend-framework

I installed a docker with apache2, MySQL, and my project (zend1).
I can't import my big database to MySQL in the docker so I set it to the local Mysql Server 5.7 (127.0.0.1 port: 3307) where I imported all the data, and now at localhost, I still see this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.75.1' (4)' in /var/www/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=un...', 'sos', 'Unilink12', Array) #1 /var/www/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2 /var/www/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3 /var/www/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `alert...', Array) #4 /var/www/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(156): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `alert...') #5 /var/www/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(825): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('alert_log', NULL) #6 /var/www/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(847): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupMetadata() #7 /var/www/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(887): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_ in /var/www/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144

application.ini for SQL in my project is:

```
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.username = "first"
resources.db.params.password = "testpass"
resources.db.params.dbname = "project_new"
resources.db.params.host = "10.0.75.1" resources.db.params.port = 3307 
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

10.0.75.1 because its subnet address in the docker settings > network

- My user has all privileges.
- MySQL service is running MySQL is configured by MySQL Workbench
- I connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 3307 without problems.
- In my.ini I added `[mysqld] port = 3307`

Answer (score 0):

Usually the 2003 error, which states only that mysql "can't connect" to the server, indicates that the server is not running. Have you verified that the server is, in fact, running at the time you get that error?

Answer (score 0):

I just have firewall on, when i was sure its off :o